# Android Studio Error: Interface used as super class of when include firebase-core:16.0.4

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I get Error when include

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```

in builde.gradle

```
Error: Interface `com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzah(classpath class)` used as super class of `com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzbv`.
```

Comment: did you add the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a Google and Firebase Library versions mismatch. For me following combination work, If any body face problem like this :

```
//Google
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"

//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4"
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.4'
```