# Flutter Issue using jitsi_meet with stripe_payment

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, jitsi-meet

I have already using stripe_payment: ^1.0.9
When I try to use jitsi_meet: ^2.0.0 getting following issue. I think issue is 2 packages conflicting. Any Idea how to resolve it,.

R8: Program type already present: com.facebook.react.bridge.ActivityEventListener

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'.
com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 38s

[image]

Comment: This seems like a similar issue: https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo/issues/171#issuecomment-657112980

You should run `./gradlew app:dependencies` and check for duplicate dependencies

Comment: how to do that in flutter?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue

Comment: @NifalNizar did you solve it ?

Comment: I changed the packages
jitsi_meet: ^2.1.0
  stripe_sdk: ^4.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too faced the same issue
Then I changed the Stripe Plugin, then everything works fine.

**jitsi_meet: ^2.0.0**

**stripe_sdk: ^4.0.2**